# Search varchar column, only on match numeric values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column (`PRODUCTNUMBER`) of type `VARCHAR` that can contain data like this:

```
SEC123456
SEC-123456
12-35-46
123456
```

Is it's possible to run a SQL Server query where I only send '123456' as my search data and will get a match for all of the rows that `PRODUCTNUMBER` has this data in it (even if `PRODUCTNUMBER` data contain characters like `'SEC123456'`)?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tab WHERE REPLACE(PRODUCTNUMBER, '-','') LIKE '%123456%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Create Function to Extract Numeric Value

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO
```

then

```
select * from TableName where dbo.udf_GetNumeric(PRODUCTNUMBER) like '%123456%'
```

try this

Comment: This works, but Is very slow when U have millions of records. But it's my best solution so for. I Think I have to rethink and add another column in my database with a numeric value from the other column that can contain other than numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of contiguous characters:

```
select * from t where productnumber like '%123456%'
```

would work.  If it's just '-' in the data you can use replace(productnumber, '-', '').  But if it could be many other non-numeric characters, you want something like:

[SQL to return field with non-numeric characters removed in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082364/sql-to-return-field-with-non-numeric-characters-removed-in-mysql)

Comment: The issue with the LIKE  (%value%) operator is that if I have data that is "1234567" och "0123456" they will also be a match if I query "123456".